# How to add tap gesture to UICollectionViewCell subview returned from dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

What's the best method for efficiently adding a tap gesture to a subview of a `UICollectionViewCell` returned from `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` that already has a bunch of default gesture recognizers attached to it (such as a `UIScrollView`). Do I need to check and see if my one custom gesture is already attached (`scrollView.gestureRecognizers`) and if not then add it? I need my app's scrolling to be as smooth as possible so performance of the check and efficient reuse of already created resources is key. This code all takes place inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you have to check whether the gesture recognizer is already added.

Comment: @dasdom I would then think to share a single tap gesture object across all the cells (as a property in my view controller) and before adding it would check `[scrollView.gestureRecognizers containsObject:self.cellSingleTapGesture] == YES // Then skip, else add`. Does this sound like the right approach to you?

Comment: Have you profiled this and seen any speed issues? This could be premature optimisation - do the simplest thing that works until it doesn't work

Answer (score 6):

I figured out a way to do it that requires only a single, shared, tap gesture recognizer object and moves the setup code from `cellForItemAtIndexPath` (which gets called very frequently as a user scrolls) to `viewDidLoad` (which gets called once when the view is loaded). Here's the code:

```
- (void)myCollectionViewWasTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap
{
    CGPoint tapLocation = [tap locationInView:self.collectionView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:tapLocation];
    if (indexPath)
    {
        MyCollectionViewCell *cell = (MyCollectionViewCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        CGRect mySubviewRectInCollectionViewCoorSys = [self.collectionView convertRect:cell.mySubview.frame fromView:cell];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(mySubviewRectInCollectionViewCoorSys, tapLocation))
        {
            // Yay! My subview was tapped!
        }
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Invoke super
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Add tap handler to collection view
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(myCollectionViewWasTapped:)];
    [self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough, very simple outline of a possible design solution: you could subclass `UICollectionViewCell` and override its initialization methods to add the gesture recognizer to its subviews. Furthermore, if you don't want the cell to "know" about the gesture recognizer, you could create  a protocol that the data source object would conform to. The cell object would call a "setup" protocol method at the appropriate time.

Hope this helps!